# Return bounding box information and text from "TABLES" option in Amazon Textract?

Tags: python, amazon-textract

I have a series of forms that contain tables, and I am using Textract to extract the table information. I need the bounding box information along with the text in each cell of the table. The code I have generated to do this is as follows:

```
import boto3

# Initialize the Textract client
client = boto3.client('textract')

with open('table_document.pdf', 'rb') as file:
    # Call Amazon Textract to analyze the document
    response = client.analyze_document(Document={'Bytes': file.read()}, FeatureTypes=['TABLES'])

# Get the table blocks from the response
table_blocks = response['Blocks']
# Filter the blocks to only include TABLE blocks
table_blocks = [b for b in table_blocks if b['BlockType'] == 'TABLE']

# Iterate over each table block
for table_block in table_blocks:
    # Get the row blocks from the table block
    row_blocks = table_block['Relationships'][0]['Ids']
    # Sort the row blocks from top to bottom
    row_blocks.sort(key=lambda x: table_blocks[x]['Geometry']['BoundingBox']['Top'])
    # Iterate over each row block
    for row_block_id in row_blocks:
        # Get the cell blocks from the row block
        cell_blocks = table_blocks[row_block_id]['Relationships'][0]['Ids']
        # Sort the cell blocks from left to right
        cell_blocks.sort(key=lambda x: table_blocks[x]['Geometry']['BoundingBox']['Left'])
        # Iterate over each cell block
        for cell_block_id in cell_blocks:
            # Get the cell block and its text
            cell_block = table_blocks[cell_block_id]
            cell_text = cell_block['Text']
            # Get the bounding box location of the cell
            box = cell_block['Geometry']['BoundingBox']
            # Print the cell text and its bounding box location
            print(f'{cell_text}: {box}')
```

Unfortunately, I get this error when running this code:

```
      9     row_blocks = table_block['Relationships'][0]['Ids']
     10     # Sort the row blocks from top to bottom
---> 11     row_blocks.sort(key=lambda x: table_blocks[x]['Geometry']['BoundingBox']['Top'])
     12     # Iterate over each row block
     13     for row_block_id in row_blocks:

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Can someone help me solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `amazon-textract-textractor` pip package.
You can install it using `pip install amazon-textract-textractor`

This makes what you are trying to achieve much easier:

```py
from textractor import Textractor
from textractor.data.constants import TextractFeatures
extractor = Textractor(profile_name="default")
document = extractor.analyze_document(
    file_source="./table_document.pdf",
    features=[TextractFeatures.TABLES],
)
for table in document.tables:
    print(f"Table {table.id}: {table.title.text if table.title is not None else ''}")
    for cell in table.table_cells:
        print(f"[{cell.row_index}][{cell.col_index}] {cell.text} [{cell.bbox}]")
```